# The page number is missing from the bottom of the page within the manuscript

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my PhD dissertation and I noticed that the last page of the manuscript, right before the bibliography, is missing the page number. All the other pages are numbered correctly, just this one is not.
How can I correct this mistake?[image]

```
\documentclass{umthesis} 
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\copyrightpage   
\signaturepage
\chapter{Acknowledgments}  
...
\begin{abstract}  
...
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents                % Table of contents
\listoftables                   % List of Tables
\listoffigures
\mainmatter 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
...
\chapter{Chapter 2}
...
\chapter{Chapter 3}
...
\backmatter  %% <--- mandatory


\interlinepenalty=10000  % prevent split bibliography entries
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliography{umthsmpl}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The example is not complete, `\begin{document}` is missing, ...

There is `\thispagestyle{empty}`. If it is executed the page before the bibliography, it would explain the empty page number. Adding `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before the bibliography and `\thispagestyle{empty}` should help.

It is a speculation, because `\backmatter` of class `book` loaded by `umthesis` already starts a new page. Thus it seems, the bibliography does not start the back matter part.

Comment: Heiko, thanks for your reply. True that I forgot to include \begin{document} in the example. Sorry about that. I just eliminated \thispagestyle{empty} and it works! \clearpage or \cleardoublepage only created an empty page (still unnumbered). Again, thank you so much!